# HTTP Status 500 - invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named [XXXX]

Tags: java, struts2, spring-3

I am new to struts2 and I am getting following exception, my entire project got stuck due to this. I am using Struts2 and Spring 3.0

can anyone tell me what are the possible reasons to getting this kind of exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named [marginAccountAction3]
org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionsServiceImpl.determineResultPath(ConventionsServiceImpl.java:100)
org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.determinePath(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:385)
org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.handleUnknownResult(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:274)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.handleUnknownResult(DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.java:76)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:215)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:356)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

#### MarginAccountAction3.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletResponseAware;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletResponseAware;


public class MarginAccountAction3 extends AMTSBaseAction implements ServletResponseAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6034744203411681476L;

    private void clearSessionValues() {
        /*
        *
        */
    }

    private void setValuesForApproval() {
    /* 
    * 
    */
    }

    public String submitForApprovalAction(){
        setValuesForApproval();
        clearSessionValues();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

#### struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir"
        value="/home/engineer/Desktop/margin_trading/file_upload_path" />
      <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/"
        extends="jasperreports-default,struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="checkUserRole" class="checkUserRole" />
        </interceptors>

        <global-results>
            <result name="unauthorized">view/errorpages/unauthorized.jsp</result>
            <result name="sessionexpired">view/errorpages/sessionexpired.jsp</result>
            <result name="processerror">view/errorpages/sytemerror.jsp</result>
            <result name="webserviceerror">view/errorpages/webserviceerror.jsp</result>
        </global-results>

        <action name="submitForApprovalAction" class="marginAccountAction3"
            method="submitForApprovalAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="completeStack" />
            <!-- <interceptor-ref name="checkUserRole"/> -->
            <result name="success">view/successpages/success.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

#### action-bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <!--Action Beans Configuration  -->

    <bean id="marginAccountAction3" name="marginAccountAction3" class="com.amts.action.MarginAccountAction3"> 

        <property name="brokerageBD" ref="brokerageBD" />
        <property name="marginAccountBD" ref="marginAccountBD" />
        <property name="MarginCallBD" ref="MarginCallBD"/>
        <property name="documentBD" ref="documentBD"/>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Thank you!

Comment: share your action class. and where is `marginAccountAction3` defined?

Comment: I posted the action class, struts.xml and action-bean.xml and I just mention only essential code from each file

Comment: and my other action classes are working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible, and actual reason is existence of the convention plugin on the classpash. As far as you using spring plugin to delegate actions to spring via classrefbyid then you can't use convention plugin. BTW, the convention plugin is invoked because you didn't define `Action.INPUT` result in the action configuration.

```xml
<action name="submitForApprovalAction" class="marginAccountAction3"
    method="submitForApprovalAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="completeStack" />
    <!-- <interceptor-ref name="checkUserRole"/> -->
    <result name="success">view/successpages/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/path/to/whateverjspissubmittedthisaction.jsp</result>
</action>
```